# Facebook sdk 4.4.0 logInWithReadPermissions not working on iphone with iOS 9

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I am using facebook sdk 4.4.0 for iOS and i am using iphone 6 with iOS 9. logInWithReadPermissions does nothing. No errors as well. It works absolutely fine on iphone with ios8.*. Any help is highly appreciated. Please help guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are changes in iOS 9 that require you to do something in order for Facebook SDK to work. The [Facebook developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) includes instructions on how to make it work with iOS 9.

In essence, update the SDK to v4.6. Add this to your application’s Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>                
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

and:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```